# Fusion Tables API Non-Profit Use Only

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have been developing an app that uses Fusion Tables API. However I was just notified by the Fusion Table Admins that the API is not for commercial use and that they will not increase the usage quota unless your project is purely non-profit. So my question is, what alternatives exist to Fusion Tables API that are commercial friendly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that Google Spreadsheets is more than 5 to 10 times faster than Fusion Tables. Not only that, but creating and importing CSV data into a spreadsheet is simpler and faster than using Fusion Tables. Fusion Tables is not only still "Expiremental", but the entire list of feature requests have not been touched for more than year. Also most of the bugs have not been fixed. I think Fusion Tables is on its way out soon. Perhaps the next "spring cleaning".

Comment: Does Google Sheets support the same feature set, such as mapping?